# Open SQL Query Designer in SQL Server Management Studio 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, query-designer

How can I open the SQL Query Designer in SQL Server Management Studio 2008? I cannot find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have SQL Server Management Studio 2008 right now but
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

As @Kostis posted or:

> Query > Design Query in Editor...

or

> New Query > right click on new empty query created > Design Query in
>   Editor...